# Inspec/Serverspec grabbing multiple stdouts from command and describing them

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, serverspec, inspec

I'm attempting to create an inspec control that searches through every line that starts with kernel (and ignores whitespace) in /boot/grub/grub.conf and then checking every line to see if it has 'nousb' somewhere in the line. I'd like it to return a failure if nousb is not found.

My issue is that I cannot figure out a way to grab/describe multiple stdouts from the grep in the event more than one line starts with kernel. Is that something I can accomplish using .each? Here is my code:

```rb
control 'os-disable-usb-pcmcia' do
  impact 0.5
  title 'Disable USB and PCMCIA Devices'
  desc "ensure default kernel in grub has 'nousb' option"

  output = command('egrep "^[[:space:]]*kernel" /boot/grub/grub.conf')
  describe output do
    its('stdout') { should match /^\s*kernel[^#]*nousb\b/ } # match nousb anywhere in the 'kernel' line
  end
end
```

Edit for clarification.

Say I have these lines in my conf file

```
kernel 1 nousb
kernel 2
kernel 3
kernel 4
```

the test will consider it passing because the initial one matched what it was looking for despite multiple kernel lines not having the nousb requirement.

Comment: I am not sure about `chef` but 1. why would not you `egrep` for `^\s*kernel[^#]*nousb\b` and check the result for truthy? and 2. are you sure `command` returns the `stdout`, not the result of command execution (I believe it’s `0` here?)

Comment: That's a good call I will switch my egrep to exactly what I am matching for, big oversight on my part. And I think it is actually checking the stdout, since when I run the test, it passes that the output matches the pattern I'm looking for.

Comment: If it returns the `stdout`, you should be fine with what you were doing, since `match` works perfectly on multiline and `egrep` returns the plain string. There are no “multiple stdouts“ in the universe :)

Comment: The issue though is the inspec portion, the describe command that I am running on the stdout is only checking one of the lines and considering it passing, I will edit my comment and clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `file` resource and Ruby's RegExp matching (as you are already doing).

```
describe file('/boot/grub/grub.conf') do
  its(:content) { is_expected.to match /whatever/ }
end
```

EDIT to show how to do this with Ruby code instead of fancy regexps:

```
describe file('/boot/grub/grub.conf') do
  it do
    # Get all the lines in the file.
    lines = subject.content.split(/\n/)
    # Check for any line that _doesn't_ match the regexp.
    without_nousb = lines.any? {|line| line !~ /^.*?kernel.*?nousb.*?$/ }
    # Make a test assertion.
    expect(without_nousb).to be false
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out, I am however having the same issue where that describe will find one line that fits its match and mark it as passing, when I have lines that should be failing. (a line with kernel that does not have nousb on it)

Comment: Then your regexp is bad, please include it above. You probably want something like this: `is_expected.to_not match /^\s*kernel \d+(?! nousb)$/m`

Comment: He's trying to ensure that *each* kernel line has `nousb`. The :content matcher will not suffice by itself.

Comment: Hence the `to_not` reverse matcher and a negative lookahead :) But it's definitely easier to write this in Ruby code than in a super-complex regexp.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on the to_not part since the above mentions that it is expected to match, but do you have any references where I could read on doing this with Ruby instead of regex? I'm pretty new to programming overall. Thanks

Comment: @coderanger `its(:content) { is_expected.to_not match /{#regex}/m }` looks like it would work, but it doesn't. Besides being hard to read because of the inversion, what would you expect `"kernel foo\nbar" !~ /^\s*kernel.*?(?!nousb)/m` to return?

Comment: Compiling zero width assertions in my brain is beyond my skills usually, I just load up regexpal.com and try it out until I'm happy.

Comment: I added a probably clearer version that uses a bit more code.

Answer (score 0):

### Test Your Parse *Results*, Not a Content Match

You have to write some code inside the block that will parse your grub.conf file and ensure that there is a `nousb` command *for each record*. You might also try the [Augeas lens for grub](http://augeas.net/docs/references/1.4.0/lenses/files/grub-aug.html) to validate the grub.conf for you. For example:

```
describe 'validate kernel parameters' do
  it 'should include a "nousb" parameter on each line' do
    # 1. parse your file however you like, then
    # 2. store result as a Boolean.
    expect(result).to be_true
  end
end
```

### Check Running Kernel

Alternatively, if you only care about the result of the *running* kernel, you can [check the value](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48602/17673) with something similar to:

```
# 1. read the remote's /proc/cmdline however you like, then
# 2. evaluate your match.
expect(command_line_contents).to match /\bnousb\b/
```

Comment: This is not related to InSpec (or Serverspec's remote mode) as it does not run on the target.

Comment: @coderanger This is covered by "parse the file however you like." I'm not prescribing the method for parsing the remote file; I'm explaining how to create an effective spec for the validation.

Comment: With the edit, this is now better :) Before you had a `File.read` which will have no effect on a remote system.

Answer (score -1):

I finally got the question. Since you want to check all kernels:

```
output = command('egrep "^[[:space:]]*kernel" /boot/grub/grub.conf')
ok = output.split("\n")
           .group_by { |line| line[/(?<=kernel )(\S*)/] }
           .map { |kernel, lines| lines.any? { |line| line =~ /nousb/ } }
           .all?

describe output do
  # OK must be TRUE
end
```

Here we:

- split the output by lines
- group lines by kernel name (regexp might require adjustment)
- map the hash `{ kernel ⇒ lines }` to true/false, depending on whether `nousb` is presented
- check that all kernels have this `nousb` line.

The code above is aware of `grub.cfg` might contain many lines for the same kernel. 
Hope it helps.